# How to extract only specific date/times in the following format: (time am/pm (EST) date) in vba access

Tags: vba, datetime, ms-access, parsing

I've been tasked with going through a database that dedicates a column to a description of the event that has occurred in the business and splitting the description into multiple separate columns. The individuals who enter these messages are giving a basic description of the event and the time and date at which it had occurred. Eventually these vba commands will be translated to SQL equivalents so the programmers can implement this into the system, but for now I'm working in vba (which I just started learning yesterday) so that I can run queries to see if the code I'm writing actually works.

Anyway, the problem that I'm having is the formal of the date and time. One of the entries is:

12:13 a.m. (EST) July 30

another example is:

01:49 (GMT) Feb. 13

As you can see, they are using abbreviations for only some of the months, and are reporting the time in different time-zones, which makes this even more complex.

Some entries don't have a leading 0 for the time.

I was wondering if you had any ideas on where to start. Initially I thought about looking for the (EST) or (GMT) parts of the string and then taking a chunk out from either sides of it, but I'm not quite sure that would work seeing as some months are abbreviated and some times dont have leading zeroes.

Also, I should say that these times are within the long message string itself. There is no standard on where these times are placed within the string.

Any help would be fantastic - really If you could just point me in the right direction, or even tell me that this isn't worth it that would be a big help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an expression like this:

```
TextDate = "12:13 a.m. (EST) July 30"
TrueDate = CDate(Split(TextDate, ")")(1)) + CDate(Replace(Split(TextDate, "(")(0), ".", ""))
```

That doesn't, however, take the *timezone* into account - that would be a task of its own. And it has no idea of the year, thus the current year is returned.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sure I'll be able to get by with this.